# Deploy DACPAC to SQL Server - Create Database fails

Tags: sql-server, deployment, dacpac

I am trying to publish my new database created in a Visual Studio 2012 Database Project to our SQL Server 2012 environment.  I can go to the server and right click on 'Databases' and create a new database with no issues, however when I try to publish my database I get an error that CREATE DATABASE permission is denied in database `master`.

Does any one know why I can create it directly on the server but can't when trying to publish from Visual Studio?

Thanks,
Leslie

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a permission issue.

> **Permissions**
>
> A DAC can only be deployed by members of the sysadmin or
> serveradmin fixed server roles, or by logins that are in the dbcreator
> fixed server role and have ALTER ANY LOGIN permissions. The built-in
> SQL Server system administrator account named sa can also deploy a
> DAC. Deploying a DAC with logins to SQL Database requires membership
> in the loginmanager or serveradmin roles. Deploying a DAC without
> logins to SQL Database requires membership in the dbmanager or
> serveradmin roles.